# Modified Tower of Hanoi

Tags: algorithm, math, towers-of-hanoi

We all know that the minimum number of moves required to solve the classical towers of hanoi problem is 2<sup>n</sup>-1. Now, let us assume that some of the discs have same size. What would be the minimum number of moves to solve the problem in that case.

Example, let us assume that there are three discs. In the classical problem, the minimum number of moves required would be 7. Now, let us assume that the size of disc 2 and disc 3 is same. In that case, the minimum number of moves required would be:

1. Move disc 1 from a to b.
2. Move disc 2 from a to c.
3. Move disc 3 from a to c.
4. Move disc 1 from b to c.

which is 4 moves. Now, given the total number of discs n and the sets of discs which have same size, find the minimum number of moves to solve the problem. This is a challenge by a friend, so pointers towards solution are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider a tower of size `n`. The top disk has to be moved 2<sup>n-1</sup> times, the second disk 2<sup>n-2</sup> times, and so on, until the bottom disk has to be moved just once, for a total of 2<sup>n</sup>-1 moves. Moving each disk takes exactly one turn.

```
   1      moved 8 times
  111     moved 4 times
 11111    moved 2 times
1111111   moved 1 time   => 8 + 4 + 2 + 1  ==  15
```

Now if *x* disks have the same size, those have to be in consecutive layers, and you would always move them towards the same target stack, so you could just as well collapse those to just one disk, requiring *x* turns to be moved. You could consider those multi-disks to be *x* times as 'heavy', or 'thick', if you like.

```
   1
  111                       1      moved 8 times
  111       collapse       222     moved 4 times, taking 2 turns each
 11111    ----------->    11111    moved 2 times
1111111                  3333333   moved 1 time, taking 3 turns
1111111                            => 8 + 4*2 + 2 + 1*3  ==  21
1111111
```

Now just sum those up and you have your answer.

Here's some Python code, using the above example: Assuming you already have a list of  the 'collapsed' disks, with `disks[i]` being the weight of the collapsed disk in the `i`th layer, you can just do this:

```py
disks = [1, 2, 1, 3]           # weight of collapsed disks, top to bottom
print sum(d * 2**i for i, d in enumerate(reversed(disks)))
```

If instead you have a list of the sizes of the disks, like on the left side, you could use this algorithm:

```py
disks = [1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7]  # size of disks, top to bottom
last, t, s = disks[-1], 1, 0
for d in reversed(disks):
    if d < last: t, last = t*2, d
    s = s + t
print s
```

Output, in both cases, is `21`, the required number of turns.

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on the distribution of the discs that are the same size. If you have n=7 discs and they are all the same size then the answer is 7 (or n). And, of course the standard problem is answered by 2<sup>n</sup>-1.

As tobias_k suggested, you can group same size discs. So now look at the problem as moving groups of discs. To move a certain number of groups, you have to know the size of each group

**examples**

### 1

```
n=7   //disc sizes (1,2,3,3,4,5,5)
g=5   //group sizes (1,1,2,1,2)
      //group index (1,2,3,4,5)

number of moves = sum( g-size * 2^( g-count - g-index ) )

in this case
moves = 1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 2*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 2*2^0
      = 16 + 8 + 8 + 2 + 2
      = 36
```

### 2

```
n=7   //disc sizes (1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
g=1   //group sizes (7)
      //group index (1)

number of moves = sum( g-size * 2^( g-count - g-index ) )

in this case
moves = 7*2^0
      = 7
```

### 3

```
n=7   //disc sizes (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
g=7   //group sizes (1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
      //group index (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

number of moves = sum( g-size * 2^( g-count - g-index ) )

in this case
moves = 1*2^6 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0
      = 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1
      = 127
```

Interesting note about the last example, and the standard hanoi problem: sum(2<sup>n-1</sup>) = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Github gist in C for this problem. I am attaching a link to it, may be useful to somebody, I hope.
[Modified tower of Hanoi problem with one or more disks of the same size](https://gist.github.com/as2d3/5fd0e4fc4ad909f9653a679d99fd3cdf)

There are n types of disks. For each type, all disks are identical. In array `arr`, I am taking the number of disks of each type. `A`, `B` and `C` are pegs or towers.

Method `swap(int, int)`, `partition(int, int)` and `qSort(int, int)` are part of my implementation of the quicksort algorithm.

Method `toh(char, char, char, int, int)` is the Tower of Hanoi solution.

How it is working: Imagine we compress all the disks of the same size into one disk. Now we have a problem which has a general solution to the Tower of Hanoi. Now each time a disk moves, we add the total movement which is equal to the total number of that type of disk.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DieterMeemken I have added a Edit to my answer. Hope that helps.